# Java - How to get SAML Assertion User Attributes

Tags: java, attributes, single-sign-on, saml, sap-cloud-platform

I have an saml sso connection between my java app and ADFS 2.0.
The connection is working good but I have some difficult to get the assertion user attributes like email in my Java servlet.

The Assertion part of my SAML RESPONSE :

[image]

I tried something like that but it's return a null value.
Based on the topic in this link : https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/9e2e0d7e91cc44e79901a756bf7b2d88.html

```
import com.sap.security.um.user.PersistenceException;
import com.sap.security.um.user.UnsupportedUserAttributeException;
import com.sap.security.um.user.User;
import com.sap.security.um.user.UserProvider;
import com.sap.security.um.service.UserManagementAccessor;

@Resource
private UserProvider userProvider;

User user = null;
String email = "";
try {
    // Read the currently logged in user from the user storage
    user =  userProvider.getUser(request.getRemoteUser());
    email = "Email: " + user.getAttribute("email");
} catch (UnsupportedUserAttributeException | PersistenceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: are you looking for Java code to parse XML?

Comment: No.  I'm trying to get saml attribute in my java code.

Comment: can you post some code for userProvider and userSAP?

Comment: Ok no problem, i'm going to update my post

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the SDK for Java EE 6 Web Profile as that's the code you're using? Are you using a SAP Cloud Platform application, i.e. using SAP ID service as the IdP? You say you're using ADFS as the IdP i.e. Active Directory

Comment: does this help? If you're using SAP Cloud Platform you need an IdP mapping file. https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3801304

Comment: Yes my app is hosted on SAP Cloud Platform (SCP) and I'm using SDK for Java EE 6 Web Profile. IdP is a good solutions but currently my department want to use the ADFS (Active Directory Federation Service) directly as a trusted identity provider on SCP. Like I say it works, I just need to know how to get email attribute.

Comment: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3801304 solve my issue. Thank you very much codebrane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue is solved. It was a specific configuration problem. 
The solution is accessible [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3801304)
Thank's to codebrane.